# Interface Oracle Contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle-contract

I am following the CryptoZombies tutorial to create an Oracle Interface.
However, I am having an error in Smart Contract which will be my interface, according to the tutorial it is the same, 2 details that are different is the "pragma" version, in CryptoZombie they are using version 0.5.0, however I am all versions from 0.4 on, the second detail is the name of the function that I have customized for my case.

My code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract GhilOracleInterface {
  function getAmountAvailable() public returns (uint256);
}
```

Output:

```
TypeError: Contract "GhilOracleInterface" should be marked as abstract.
 --> project:/contracts/GhilOracleInterface.sol:4:1:
  |
4 | contract GhilOracleInterface {
  | ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: Missing implementation:
 --> project:/contracts/GhilOracleInterface.sol:5:3:
  |
5 |   function getAmountAvailable() public returns (uint256);
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

,TypeError: Functions without implementation must be marked virtual.
 --> project:/contracts/GhilOracleInterface.sol:5:3:
  |
5 |   function getAmountAvailable() public returns (uint256);
  |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is valid for solidity < 0.6.0 but not above as you can see [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/060-breaking-changes.html).

> The new keyword abstract can be used to mark contracts as abstract. It has to be used if a contract does not implement all its functions.

> Functions without implementation outside an interface have to be marked virtual.

You are using a compiler with a version > 0.6.0, this is why you get the errors.

So you either adopt the new abstract / virtual keywords and use pragma > 0.6.0. Or keep your current code and specify a pragma < 0.6.0.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.9.0;

abstract contract GhilOracleInterface {
  function getAmountAvailable() public virtual returns (uint256);
}
```

If you are doing a tutorial, maybe it's best that you specify a pragma compatible with the code you are being provided.

such as :

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
```

You will also need to use a compiler that fits this version range.

On Remix, you can do this easily in the Solidity Compiler tab :

[image]

If you are using truffle you can edit your configuration file to select the last 0.5.x version:

```
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.5",
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and to use with newer versions what would my code look like then? Do you have an example?

Comment: I edited my answer with the exemple.